# pip3.exe accesses Python 2 install

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I'm trying to use Python 3's `pip` from the command line in Windows 10. `pip3` is in my Python 3 install; however, when called it apparently points to my Python 2 install. Why might `pip3.exe` live in a different Python installation than the one it actually modifies, and how could I resolve the discrepancy?

(I know other ways to use Python 3's `pip`, such as `python3 -m pip`, and that's not what I'm asking).

[image]

Comment: Do you have both installations in your PATH variable?

Comment: Yes, I do (which is why `where python` found both). I don't think there's even a `pip3.exe` in my python 2 install, but in any case would that explain why the file `where` found was not the one executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually my `pip` executable that was broken -- calling `pip3.exe` in my Python 3 directory still somehow accessed my Python 2 install, but `python3 -m pip` actually accessed `pip` for Python 3 as expected.

Upgrading/reinstalling Python 3's `pip` with `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` seems to have fixed it!